# How can I style a send button in a comment textarea like in the facebook app?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm new at coding and I would like copy facebook app comment section where the send icon is part of the textarea and positioned at the right end.

I have experimented with the following code but when I type in the textarea, it overlaps under the send icon. And also the icon does not stay at the bottom but instead stays on top when I type many texts.
[image]
[image]
 [image]

```
<form [formGroup]="form" > 

    <ion-item-divider ></ion-item-divider>    
    <ion-item lines="none" style="height: auto; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" >
        <ion-textarea 
            formControlName="comment" 
            placeholder="Write a comment..." 
            rows="1"
            auto-grow="true"
            autofocus="true"
            mode="ios"
            maxlength="1000"
            style="
                height: auto;
                border-radius: 20px;
                box-shadow: none !important;
                width: 80%;
                background-color: #EBEDF0;
                padding-left: 9px;
            "
            autosize
        >
            <div style="float: right; margin-bottom: -50%">
                <ion-button
                    (click)="createComment()"
                    fill="clear"
                    slot="end"
                >
                    <ion-icon name="send" style="font-size: 30px;"></ion-icon>
                </ion-button>
            </div>
        </ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `ionic`, but you could use a CSS flexbox. But huge protip: you should generally avoid using `float` for layouts and positioning elements - only use it for its original purpose: images inline in text and typographical features like drop-caps and illuminated text.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use Ionic but here is the general idea. You wrap the input and the icon in a container div that will look like the input field. You use `calc(100% - 25px)` to set the size of the textarea and `position: absolute;` with `bottom: 10px;` to keep the icon at the bottom.

```js
// NOT IMPORTANT, FOR TEXTAREA AUTO-GROW
$('textarea').autoResize();
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

textarea {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: calc(100% - 25px);
  border: none;
}

textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.icon {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 10px;
 right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://j11y.io/demos/plugins/jQuery/autoresize.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/31f4337ba1.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <i class="icon fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved my problem by using your .icon class so that the send icon stays at the bottom right then I just adjusted the padding-left of the textarea to give space to the send icon.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by:
Adjusting the position of the send icon to stay at the bottom right.
Then, just adjusted the left padding of the textarea.